# What is the optimal measuring time split for limited measuring time between signal+background and background in a Poisson counting experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, poisson-distribution, measurement-error, poisson-process

I’m trying to figure out the best split of time between measuring either background or signal+background in a counting experiment in the case where we have prior estimates for the signal and background rates and then in the case where we have no prior knowledge about the mean signal count rate. The goal is to get the statistically best measurement of the background-subtracted signal rate.

Assuming we have only a limited time T to perform measurements and there is no timing uncertainty. What’s a good way to approach this problem?

My first idea is to use the $\sqrt{N}$ Poisson errors, propagate them for the rates (our measurement being counts) and minimise the function in the first case, and in the second case find the median of the minima of this function over all possible signal rates. Any comments or suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!